# How to randomize a set of strings?

Tags: java, string, random

Hello I am a beginner at java, and I was having problems randomizing a set of strings (5). If you look under "cute" loop, I am able to randomize the list, but it only outputs numbers 1 - 5 instead of outputting the strings that i want. What am I doing wrong here?

Basically, what i want is for the user to type in what kind of video they want to watch, and then have the program randomize from the category they chose 5 of the videos and pick one from it and output it to the user.

```
if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("cute")){

    int cutelist = rand.nextInt(5);

    if (cutelist == 0) {
        String cute1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdCVijVT7Wk";
    } else if (cutelist == 1) {
        String cute2 = "http://youtu.be/-XCvPptsfhI?t=7s";
    } else if (cutelist == 2) {
        String cute3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nkEPsSsH68";
    } else if (cutelist == 3) {
        String cute4 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ-bJFVJ2P0";
    } else {
        String cute5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=argCvDpk_KQ";
    }

    String cute1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdCVijVT7Wk";
    String cute2 = "http://youtu.be/-XCvPptsfhI?t=7s";
    String cute3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nkEPsSsH68";
    String cute4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ-bJFVJ2P0";
    String cute5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=argCvDpk_KQ";

    System.out.println("Here's a funny you can watch:" + cutelist);

}
```

Comment: You are printing the int variable `cutelist`, not the string ones you created `cute1`, `cute2`, ...

Comment: Perhaps it should be version 0.001 ALPHA instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the random number.

```
int cutelist = rand.nextInt(5);

...

System.out.println("Here's a funny you can watch:" + cutelist);
```

If you want to print out one of your string values (`cute1`, `cute2`, etc.) you should put them in an array or `ArrayList` and use the `cutelist` variable as an index.

You want something along the lines of:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(5);
String[] videos = new String[5];

videos[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdCVijVT7Wk";
videos[1] = "http://youtu.be/-XCvPptsfhI?t=7s";
videos[2] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nkEPsSsH68";
videos[3] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ-bJFVJ2P0";
videos[4] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=argCvDpk_KQ";

System.out.println("Here's a funny you can watch:" + videos[index]);
```

See the [Java Tutorial on Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information. Be sure to note that there are other ways to initialize an array besides the one illustrated above.

Comment: Thanks, i already have a basic understanding on arrays, however i still dont know how to randomize them, which is my real issue.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArrayGoesHere))` - Like that?

Comment: @Takendarkk sobasically i create an array for "cutelist" then i would add this line of code in? 



     Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cutelist))

Comment: Yes that will mix up all the elements like first one will maybe become 4th and 2nd might become first etc. I'm just not sure if that's what you are needing.

Comment: @codeacode Do you really need to mix up the elements of the array, or do you need to pick one at random?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I need it to pick one at random

Comment: @codeacode Then you can just put them in an array and use a random `int` as an index to pick one. You don't need to shuffle the array.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I've been trying to do that for the past 2 hours

Comment: @BilltheLizard I just got it working, thanks for helping out!

Comment: @BilltheLizard I did it differently, I think it works because i got a random url most of the time, however I cant post my code to show you